# When clicking an irc:// link, a new instance of chatzilla opens instead of the existing one being used

Tags: firefox, multiple-instances, chatzilla

That is my problem in a nutshell.

I'm running Win7 32-bit. I have chatzilla on XulRunner, so not as the Firefox add-on.
When I clock any irc:// link, a new instance of Chatzilla will be started. I have a lot of startup-commands set, so all those will be executed. I stop the new instance before it takes off, but this is rather annoying.

Firefox application setting just link to the path where the executable is, with no option to set any command-line stuff to make the existing instance be used.

Is there any firefox or windows setting that I can manipulate, so that when firefox calls chatzilla.exe, the existing instance is used instead of a new one opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check chatzilla setting for this. I think there is no 'external' way to achieve this